# do special forms use only special-symbols?

Tags: clojure

executing the following commands in REPL

```
    (symbol-special? 'do) ;=> true
    (type 'do)            ;=> Symbol
    (doc do)              ;=>.. it is a Special form...
```

and the same thing for let

```
    (symbol-special? 'let) ;=> FALSE
    (type 'let)            ;=> Symbol
    (doc let)              ;=>.. it is a Special form...
```

I know let is a macro that uses the special-symbol let*, is there a relationship between special-symbols and special-forms?

regards,

Answer (score 1):

"Special forms" are those that receive special handling from the compiler. These are precisely the forms that have a "special symbol" in operator position.

`let` is described as a special form in the documentation, because `let*` is considered to be an implementation detail and users are encouraged to think of `let` as a basic building block of the language. At least that's my understanding.

(NB. users of other Lispy languages may attach somewhat different meanings to the two terms. This usage is established in the Clojure community.)

Comment: To complement Michal's answer, I would just add that some symbols are not considered special but behave like macros: anything starting or ending by a period.